# Streaming AP: Tracked keywords result in "error: Non-UTF-8 code... but no encoding declared"

Tags: python, twitter, utf-8, tweepy

I have a running code using tweepy's stream listener to stream tweets. It works just fine and I have run it a couple of times successfully, both using arabic, English, and French keywords combined.

For some reason, when I insert my whole set of keywords (397) the code results in the error reading

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xd9' in file twitter_streaming_copy.py on line 67, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Quite oddly, I have tried to run the code using different parts of the set of keywords and it works fine, it is only when I put them all together that is stops working. Any idea? Here is my code: (I'm using python 3)

```
# Chap02-03/twitter_streaming.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys 
import string 
import time
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream 
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
 consumer_key = ".."
 consumer_secret = ".."
 access_key = ".-."
 access_secret = ".."


 class CustomListener(StreamListener): 
  """Custom StreamListener for streaming Twitter data.""" 

   def __init__(self, fname):
     safe_fname = format_filename(fname) 
     self.outfile = "stream_%s.jsonl" % safe_fname 

   def on_data(self, data): 
     try: 
       with open(self.outfile, 'a') as f: 
         f.write(data) 
         return True 
     except BaseException as e: 
       sys.stderr.write("Error on_data: {}\n".format(e)) 
       time.sleep(5) 
     return True 

   def on_error(self, status): 
     if status == 420: 
       sys.stderr.write("Rate limit exceeded\n") 
       return False 
     else: 
       sys.stderr.write("Error {}\n".format(status)) 
       return True 

 def format_filename(fname): 
  """Convert fname into a safe string for a file name. 

   Return: string 
  """ 
   return ''.join(convert_valid(one_char) for one_char in fname) 

 def convert_valid(one_char): 
  """Convert a character into '_' if "invalid". 

   Return: string 
  """ 
   valid_chars = "-_.%s%s" % (string.ascii_letters, string.digits) 
   if one_char in valid_chars: 
     return one_char 
   else: 
     return '_' 

 if __name__ == '__main__': 
   query = sys.argv[1:] # list of CLI arguments 
   query_fname = ' '.join(query) # string 
   auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
   auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
   api = tweepy.API(auth)
   twitter_stream = Stream(auth, CustomListener(query_fname)) 
   twitter_stream.filter(track=['saudi لبنان', 'iran لبنان', 'iran lebanon', 'ايران لبنان', 'hezbollah lebanon', 'حزب الله لبنان', 'saoudite liban', 'iran liban', 'hezbollah liban'], async=True)
```

Comment: Please don't manually indent your lines when posting. Copy and paste your code into the question, select the code, then use the `{}` toolbar button to indent it. You now have weird, invalid indentation throughout your code.

Comment: oh thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

You haven't saved your source file as UTF-8. Configure your editor correctly.

Alternatively, adjust your coding comment at the top; the default for Python 3 is UTF-8 but if you used a different codec you need to specify it in that comment. However,tThe encoding comment should appear in the *first **two** lines* of your file. You have it set on the third line. Quoting from the [PEP linked in the error message](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#defining-the-encoding):

> To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must be placed into the source files **either as first or second line in the file**[.]

*(Bold emphasis mine)*

Re-arrange your comments to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: <your codec> -*-
# Chap02-03/twitter_streaming.py
```

I moved the first comment down; the `#!` line **must** be the first line in the file for it to work. You could also just remove it altogether, since you were not using it.

Comment: thanks, I completely overlooked this. But as mentioned the code itself worked even with the arabic keywords. I eliminated two words (I didn't list the 400 keywords in the above code), because those two had specific features: إ and  أ , although these are normal arabic letters it seems python had problems recognising them. Without those two the streaming worked just fine... but thanks for the help!

Comment: @JosephinaK.: there is not really anything special about those two codepoints. Perhaps you are dealing with composed characters in one place and decomposed in the other? Both codepoints can be decomposed to a U+0627 ARABIC LETTER ALEF together with either U+0654 or U+0655 (ARABIC HAMZA ABOVE and BELOW). See [Normalizing Unicode](//stackoverflow.com/q/16467479) on how to convert between the two forms.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced a similar error with the following code by saving the file as `Windows-1256` (Arabic):

```
# Chap02-03/twitter_streaming.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = ['saudi لبنان', 'iran لبنان', 'iran lebanon', 'ايران لبنان', 'hezbollah lebanon', 'حزب الله لبنان', 'saoudite liban', 'iran liban', 'hezbollah liban']
```

Output:

```
  File "C:\test.py", line 4
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe1' in file C:\test.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

@Martijn's answer is correct that the `coding` line must be in the first two lines, but UTF-8 is the default encoding in Python 3 anyway.  If the file was saved in UTF-8, it would have worked even with the comment on the wrong line, but the file must also be saved in the declared encoding.

Comment: The error shows they get a 0xd9 byte, not a 0xe1 byte, so the actual codec used differs.

Comment: @martijn I know, that's why I said "a similar error" :^)  None of the Arabic legacy encodings I tried gave the exact error.

Comment: Indeed, there are exactly 0 codecs that would produce `\xd9` for that text.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You mean a question on SO doesn't contain the code that reproduces the error? Inconceivable! ;^)

Comment: Hi! Sorry I did not include the 400 keywords I used, since it's sensitive material... As commented above, the error, I think, was caused by two keywords that included some specific features... I am, however interested in  knowning how to save the file in the declared encoding. Because when opening the jsonl file, I only see the \u characters instead of the arabic text. Where in the "f.write(data) " part can I change that?

Comment: @JosephinaK.: `\u` escape sequences are part and parcel of the JSON format. Just decode the JSON (using the `json` module) and you'll get valid Unicode text from that.